# How to resolve Symfony 4 webpack/encore loading error?

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I'm having problem with Symfony webpack encore and getting following error.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/build/js/app.js”.
```

Tried with both with or without asset.

```
 <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Tried with Firefox, Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figure out what was the problem,

I was doing following code

```
{% block javascripts %}
      {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
      <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

inside the base.html.twig, 
but later when I moved to template where it was extended then it worked.

Comment: i don't think you need to include <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script> as this is already being included in {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

Answer (score 0):

Did you also tried to use it like this?

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked the mistake was I was doing inside base template and I  missed {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }} to write.